# Hyperref: Include part number for cross-references to chapters

Tags: hyperref, parts

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \part{First Part}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \label{inner} Some text.

    \part{Second Part}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \ref{inner}
\end{document}
```

that produces a reference `1` for the label `inner`. How can I include the number of the part associated with the chapter in this reference, i.e. automatically create a cross-reference of the form `I.1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel provides a nifty mechanism for "prefixing" material to cross-references to counters. For every counter variable defined somewhere via a `\newcounter` macro named, say, `somecounter`, LaTeX automatically creates an auxilliary macro named `\p@somecounter`, and the value of this macro is automatically prefixed to the result of a `\ref` command that references the counter `somecounter`.

By default, these auxilliary prefixing macros are empty, but it's straightforward to modify them via `\renewcommand` instructions. For the case at hand, you could achieve your objective by adding the instructions

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@chapter}{\thepart.} % prefix "\thepart." to the number of the chapter
\makeatother
```

to the preamble, before loading `hyperref`. (The `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` instructions are needed because the macro `\p@chapter` contains the character `@` which normally has category code "other".)