# How do I include the book/part name in the cross-references (if cross-book/part)?

Tags: cross-referencing, parts, books

My document structure is basically a collection of other smaller documents. I decided not to go down the [xr-hyper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41539/18648) road and having individual PDF documents, because the requirement in the end is a single file anyway. So, instead, I decided to create one big LaTeX document with my sub-documents as *books*, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand*{\thebook}{\Alph{book}} % "Book A", "Book B", etc.
\begin{document}
\book{maindoc}
\chapter{maindoc first chapter}
\label{chap:maindoc-first}
\chapter{maindoc second chapter}
\label{chap:maindoc-second}

\book{extradoc}
\setcounter{chapter}{0} % reset chapter counter with each book
\chapter{extradoc first chapter}
\label{chap:extradoc-first}
\chapter{extradoc second chapter}
\label{chap:extradoc-second}
As shown in \ref{chap:maindoc-first}, and further research in \ref{chap:extradoc-first} ...

\book{anotherdoc}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{anotherdoc chapter}
\end{document}
```

Now this `As shown in \ref{chap:maindoc-first}` will render as if the chapter was in the scope of the current part. What I'd like to accomplish is something like:

- As shown in chapter 1 of the maindoc and chapter 1...
- As shown in chapter 1 (maindoc) and chapter 1 ...
- As shown in (1, maindoc) and (1) ...
- As shown in A-1 and 1 ...

However, as most references are within the documents themselves, I don't want to prefix *all* of the references as in [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172962/18648).

How can I accomplish this? Is there a way to determine the scope of the reference and include the prefix conditionally?

Ultimately, I'd like to do the same for references to theorems, figures, tables, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `memoir`, you should make use of the cross-referencing facilities provided by the class. These are covered in chapter 16 of the [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).

`memoir` does, however, have some fairly definite ideas about formatting and so does not always provide much flexibility beyond those ideas. In this case, it thinks that cross-references to other parts of the document should be capitalised. If you prefer to avoid this, you need to provide alternatives.

The following are based on the versions provided by `memoir`:

```
\aref% based on \Aref
\bref% \Bref
\cref% \Cref
\sref% \Sref
```

and the lower-cased names are provided by:

```
\lcbookrefname% based on \bookrefname
\lcchapterrefname% \chapterrefname
\lcsectionrefname% identical to \sectionrefname
\lcappendixrefname% based on \appendixrefname
```

This allows you to set references as desired when combined with the `\titleref` command provided by `memoir`.

To automate this, a `\chapref{}` command is provided which should produce references formatted according to the first possibility you listed. You can create other commands to achieve the other formats in a similar way.

**Note:** I suspect that the way I've coded the `\chapref` command, at the very least, may not be the best way to do it. ***Caveat emptor...***

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand*{\thebook}{\Alph{book}} % "Book A", "Book B", etc.
\newcommand*{\aref}[1]{\lcappendixrefname\ref{#1}}
\newcommand*{\bref}[1]{\lcbookrefname\ref{#1}}
\newcommand*{\cref}[1]{\lcchapterrefname\ref{#1}}
\newcommand*{\sref}[1]{\lcsectionrefname\ref{#1}}
\newcommand*{\lcbookrefname}{book~}
\newcommand*{\lcchapterrefname}{chapter~}
\newcommand*{\lcsectionrefname}{\S}
\newcommand*{\lcappendixrefname}{appendix~}
\makeatletter
\def\chapref@book#1:#2-#3\@nil{#2}
\newcommand*{\chapref}[1]{%
  \edef\tempa{\expandafter\chapref@book#1\@nil}%
  \edef\tempb{\ref{book:\tempa}}%
  \edef\tempc{\thebook}%
  \ifx\tempb\tempc
  \cref{#1}%
  \else
  \cref{#1} of the \titleref{book:\tempa}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \book{maindoc}
  \label{book:maindoc}
  \chapter{maindoc first chapter}
  \label{chap:maindoc-first}
  \chapter{maindoc second chapter}
  \label{chap:maindoc-second}

  \book{extradoc}
  \label{book:extradoc}
  \setcounter{chapter}{0} % reset chapter counter with each book
  \chapter{extradoc first chapter}
  \label{chap:extradoc-first}
  \chapter{extradoc second chapter}
  \label{chap:extradoc-second}

  Manually using the facilities of the class:

  As shown in \cref{chap:maindoc-first} of the \titleref{book:maindoc}, and further research in \cref{chap:extradoc-first} ...

  \noindent Or using the custom command:

  As shown in \chapref{chap:maindoc-first}, and further research in \chapref{chap:extradoc-first} \dots

  \book{anotherdoc}
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \chapter{anotherdoc chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: manual and automated chapter references]